# Android lint export to HTML not working for large volume of inspection result

Tags: android, intellij-idea, lint

I am performing static code analysis at project level using Android Lint (Analyze-->Inspect Code...) from Android Studio. The inspection result contains hundreds of errors & thousands of warnings. When I am trying to export the result to HTML, it's unable to do it.

It shows an error message

> "Windows can't find index.html",

as it fails to create & export the result to that file. To reduce the volume of analysis data, I even tried to set lint option "ignoreWarnings" to true in the app-level gradle file, but still the lint reports thousands of warnings. I also tried to create a sample android app and run the lint tool. As the inspection result for this sample app is very small (only 10 errors + warnings), the lint could successfully export the result to HTML file which can then be viewed in browser.

Comment: For what it's worth, IntelliJ Community editons does't handle large reports very well. saving it to HTML takes for ever, to the point you give up waiting for it. If you keep waiting, you might get a file of 100+ MB ;)